# Elasticity tensor in terms of principal stretches

Tags: classical-mechanics, multivariable-calculus

Suppose we are given a frame-indifferent isotropic function
$W:GL_+(3) \to [0,\infty)$, where $GL_+(3)$ denotes the set of all real $(3\times 3)$-matrices with positive determinant.
We can write $W(F)$ in terms of the principal stretches (i.e. singular values) of $F$. More specifically, there exists a function
$f:[0,\infty)^3\to[0,\infty)$
such that
$$
W(F) = f(\lambda_1(F), \lambda_2(F), \lambda_3(F)),
$$
where $\lambda_1(F)\geq \lambda_2(F)\geq\lambda_3(F)\geq 0$ are the singular values of $F$. 
Assume that $W$ and $f$ are smooth. I want to write the elasticity tensor $\frac{\partial^2 W}{\partial F^2}$ in terms of $f$ and $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$.

My ansatz is the following: Symmetry of $\frac{\partial^2 W}{\partial F^2}$ reduces the degrees of freedom from 81 to 45. Furthermore, every rotation $R\in SO(3)$ can be uniquely written as a product 
$$
R = R_z(\alpha_3)R_y(\alpha_2)R_x(\alpha_1),
$$
where $R_w(\alpha_i)\in SO(3)$ with $w\in \{x,y,z\}, i\in\{1,2,3\},$ denotes the rotation around the $w$-axis by the angle $\alpha_i$. By frame-indifference and isotropy we have for every matrix $F\in GL_+(3)$
$$
W(F)=W(R_z(\alpha_6)R_y(\alpha_5)R_x(\alpha_4) F R_z(\alpha_3)R_y(\alpha_2)R_x(\alpha_1))
$$
for every $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_6 \in[0,2\pi)$.
In particular,
$$
0 = \frac{\partial}{\partial\alpha_i}
W(R_z(\alpha_6)R_y(\alpha_5)R_x(\alpha_4) F R_z(\alpha_3)R_y(\alpha_2)R_x(\alpha_1))
$$
for every $i\in\{1,\dots,6\}$. This relation yields a further reduction of the degrees of freedom of $\frac{\partial^2 W}{\partial F^2}$. However, I am not sure how to go on from here. The resulting linear system seems to be very complicated and I suspect that there is a more efficient way to determine all the entries of $\frac{\partial^2 W}{\partial F^2}$ in terms of $f,\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$.

For $(3\times 2)$-matrices the answer to my question was presented by Pipkin in this paper: https://academic.oup.com/imamat/article-abstract/36/1/85/762621?redirectedFrom=fulltext
The result therein is a very compact expression. Unfortunately, there are no details of the computation provided.

Hence my question: Can anybody tell me how to compute $\frac{\partial^2 W}{\partial F^2}$ in terms of $f,\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$ (or how to improve/simplify my above ansatz)? Or does anybody know any literature where I can find the desired result?

Remark: I posted this question on math.stackexchange.com a few months ago, but it got very little attention:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3421016/elasticity-tensor-in-terms-of-principal-stretches

Comment: Isn't this, by the chain rule, mainly an issue of computing $\partial \lambda_* / \partial F$?

Comment: In the paper you cite there are only two principle stretches, and so their squares solve the characteristic equation for the square $F^* F$ (which is two-by-two). So in particular you can use the quadratic equation to write down $\lambda_*$ as algebraic expressions in terms of $F$ and find the derivatives directly. (This is the equation 6.2 in that paper) // In the $3\times 3$ case I guess you can try using the cubic formula....